# Center to screen an image with max-height and max-width

Tags: css

I try to make a feature for something like a forum. People can use a custom BBcode to generate a thumbnail of an image and onclick i see an image modal with an image with max-height & max-width for dynamic sizes.

And there is my problem with the image modal. I cant get the result to properly center to screen. When formatting like this, the image centers horizontally but sticks vertically to the top. What can I do?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapperDiv">
    <img class="fullimage" src="$someUrl">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapperDiv {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;

    height: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;

    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  

    z-index: 10000;
}

 .fullimage {
    height: 100%;

    max-height: 500px;
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to you flex instead, like this :

```
.wrapperDiv {
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.fullimage {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/GuillaumeGautier/pen/rNxxKJZ

Comment: Ah, didnt even thought of flex. But your solution in combination with top:0 and left:0 totally works! thx!